# Loading dba.stackexchange.com in Google Chrome causes WebGL error

Tags: bug

When I load the https://dba.stackexchange.com site I get an error message in Google Chrome stating:

[image: Chrome Error: Rats! WebGL hit a snag.]

It doesn't always happen. By using a trial and error approach I found out that an error occurs only when the advert for **Microsoft Azure** is displayed:

[image: Chrome Web Developer Console: Microsoft Azure Ad (produces errors)]

When the advert is suppressed by blocking certain sites, then it works just fine:

[image: Chrome Web Developer Console: with blocking rules and no error]

Could a site dev have a quick look and see if it is reproducible?